# How do I get the highest key in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

d = {'apple':9,'oranges':3,'grapes':22}

How do I return the largest key/value?

Edit: How do I make a list that has this sorted by largest to lowest value?

Comment: What do you mean by "largest key/value"? Do you want the largest key, the largest value, the key/value pair with the largest key, or the key/value pair with the largest value?

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> d = {'apple':9,'oranges':3,'grapes':22}
>>> v, k = max((v, k) for k, v in d.items())
>>> k
'grapes'
>>> v
22
```

**Edit**: To sort them:

```
>>> items = sorted(((v, k) for k, v in d.items()), reverse=True)
>>> items
[(22, 'grapes'), (9, 'apple'), (3, 'oranges')]
```

Comment: +1 - but I'd do `sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [max()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max).  To get the largest key use:

```
max(d.keys())
```

Or:

```
max(d)
```

To get the largest value use:

```
max(d.values())
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the key with the highest value from your dictionary then this is the answer.

```
max(d.keys(), key=d.get)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
max(d.values())
```

Edited:

The above gives you the max value. To get the key/value pair with the max value, you could do this:

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)[0]
```

Comment: @alex There could be more than one. `d = {'apple': 22, 'oranges': 22, 'grapes': 22}`. Would any suffice?

Answer (score 0):

"""How do I print the key, too? """

```
maxval = max(d.itervalues())
maxkeys = [k for k, v in d.iteritems() if v == maxval]
```